# How to compute Map from stream, to then check property of map values?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

My requirement: I have an interface that shall only contain entries such as `public final static short SOME_CONST = whatever`. The catch: the short constants need to be *unique*. And in when there are duplicates, I am mainly interested in having the SOME_CONST_A, SOME_CONST_B, ... names causing the conflict.

I wrote the below test to test that via reflection. It works, but I find it clunky and not very elegant:

```
@Test
public void testIdsAreUnique() {
    Map<Short, List<String>> fieldNamesById = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    Arrays.stream(InterfaceWithIds.class.getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(f -> f.getClass().equals(Short.class))
            .forEach((f) -> {
        Short key = null;
        String name = null;
        try {
            key = f.getShort(null);
            name = f.getName();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        fieldNamesById.computeIfAbsent(key, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(name);
    });

    assertThat(fieldNamesById.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)), is(Collections.emptyMap()));
}
```

Is there a way to avoid that intermediate local map instance?

( bonus question: is there a nicer way to shorten the lambda that fills the map with key/value pairs? )

Comment: You do know this is a very common anti-pattern, of only  constants in interfaces, right?

Comment: @Eugene Many things our legacy framework asks me to do aren't exactly pro-patterns. Still, I have to deal with them, and work around them ...

Comment: `f.getShort(null);` will throw a NPE

Comment: @LuCio nope, that works fine. It is a static constant, remember.

Comment: @GhostCat Oh yes .. it's an interface with constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a stream that's grouping fields by the static value. Note some comments about other changes/corrections

```
Map<Short, List<String>> fieldNamesById = 
        Arrays.stream(InterfaceWithIds.class.getDeclaredFields())

         //using short.class, not Short.class
        .filter(f -> f.getType().equals(short.class)) 

        //group by value, mapping fields to their names in a list
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(f -> getValue(f),
                Collectors.mapping(Field::getName, Collectors.toList())));
```

The method called to read the value is below (primarily meant to avoid try/catch blocks in the stream):

```
private static Short getValue(Field f) {
    try {
        return f.getShort(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a check for the modifiers as well, until I realized: it is an interface, so all members are implicitly public final static. So that check is redundant ;-)

Comment: @ernest_k and now you can reduce the entire map ( where list.size() > 1 ) to a single string, like and answer below and simply assert that against an empty string

Comment: There’s no need to use `equals` for classes, `f.getType() == short.class` is sufficient. @Eugene I’d rather use `Collectors.groupingBy(…, HashMap::new, …)` to ensure a mutable map, followed by `fieldNamesById.values().removeIf(l -> l.size()==1);` and finally `if(!fieldNamesById.isEmpty()) throw new AssertionError(fieldNamesById.toString());`

Comment: @Holger nice, agreed, much cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

If you want this check efficiently (normally not so much a concern for unit test), you can reduce the work by optimistically assuming that the fields have no duplicates and performing a cheap pre-test first. Further, you can use the result of this pre-test for getting the actual field with duplicates (if there are some) without a `Map`.

As pre-requisite, we should encapsulate the reflective operation

```
private static int fieldValue(Field f) {
    try {
        return f.getShort(null);
    }
    catch(ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

Further, we need to map the potential values of the `short` value range to a positive index for a `BitSet`:

```
private static int shortToIndex(int shortValue) {
    return Math.abs(shortValue<<1) | (shortValue>>>31);
}
```

This assumes that numbers with smaller magnitude are more common and keeps their magnitude small, to reduce the size of the resulting `BitSet`. If the values are assumed to be positive, `shortValue & 0xffff` would be preferable. If neither applies, you could also use `shortValue - Short.MIN_VALUE` instead.

Having the mapping function, we can use

```
@Test
public void testIdsAreUnique() {
    BitSet value = new BitSet(), duplicate = new BitSet();

    Field[] fields = InterfaceWithIds.class.getDeclaredFields();
    Arrays.stream(fields)
        .filter(f -> f.getType() == short.class)
        .mapToInt(f -> shortToIndex(fieldValue(f)))
        .forEach(ix -> (value.get(ix)? duplicate: value).set(ix));

    if(duplicate.isEmpty()) return; // no duplicates

    throw new AssertionError(Arrays.stream(fields)
        .filter(f -> duplicate.get(shortToIndex(fieldValue(f))))
        .map(f -> f.getName()+"="+fieldValue(f))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "fields with duplicate values: ", "")));
}
```

It first fills a bitset for all encountered values and another bitset for those encountered more than once. If the latter bitset is empty, we can return immediately as there are no duplicates. Otherwise, we can use that bitset as a cheap filter to get the field having the problematic values.

Answer (score 2):

With your actual solution you are not very far.
You could relying on `groupingBy()` and `mapping()` in a first map collect in order to collect field names by field value. 
In this way you don't need any intermediary `Map`.

```
Map<Short, List<String>> map = 
Arrays.stream(InterfaceWithIds.class.getDeclaredFields())
     .filter(f -> f.getType()
                   .getClass()
                   .equals(short.class))
     .map(f -> {
         Short key = null;
         String name = null;
         try {
             key = f.getShort(null);
             name = f.getName();
         } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
         }
         return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, name);
     })
     .collect(groupingBy(SimpleEntry::getKey, LinkedHashMap::new, mapping(e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.toList())))
     .entrySet()
     .stream()
     .filter(e -> e.getValue()
                   .size() > 1)
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

assertThat(map, is(Collections.emptyMap()));
```

Comment: After a bit of forth and back, I got your solution to work. But now things are so complicated that I feel forced to put a comment above the whole thing. Which basically means: maybe I should stick with my first solution, because that was comprehensible without any additional comment ;-O

Comment: I completely agree that your initial solution is better.

Comment: Honestly I think that you should accept and follow the ernest_k solution. It avoids the `SimpleEntry` use.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this would fit your needs, but why not simply:

```
 ...filter(..)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f.getShort(null), Field::getName))
```

If there are duplicates, this will fail with an Exception. Catch that and do `Assert.fail(...)` for example.

I hope I got the code right, typing this on the phone

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this stops on the first error. I want to collect all issues, and print them once.

Comment: @GhostCat I understood that after posting, and there are already good answers here, so I did not edit

Answer (score 1):

A few problems here. Firstly `f.getClass()` will give you the class of the `Field` instance, and not the actual class of the field. You want

```
f.getType().equals(Short.class)
```

Next, you need to remember that `Short.class` and `short.class` are different, so you actually want

```
f.getType().equals(Short.class) || f.getType().equals(short.class)
```

I would personally take advantage of that fact that `map.put` returns the previous value for the given key. Because we hope that there will never have been a previous value, we can simply call `assertNull` on the result.

Your entire test would look like this:

```
Map<Short, String> fieldNamesById = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Arrays.stream(InterfaceWithIds.class.getDeclaredFields())
    .filter(f -> f.getType().equals(Short.class) || f.getType().equals(short.class))
    .forEach((f) -> {
        Short key = null;
        String name = null;
        try {
            key = f.getShort(null);
            name = f.getName();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        assertNull(fieldNamesById.put(key, name));
    });
```

If you want to report all errors, try this:

```
List<String> problems = new ArrayList<>();

Map<Short, String> fieldNamesById = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Arrays.stream(InterfaceWithIds.class.getDeclaredFields())
    .filter(f -> f.getType().equals(Short.class) || f.getType().equals(short.class))
    .forEach((f) -> {
        Short key = null;
        String name = null;
        try {
            key = f.getShort(null);
            name = f.getName();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        String prevValue = fieldNamesById.put(key, name);
        if (prevValue != null) problems.add("key " + key + " mapped to " + name + " and " + prevValue);
    });

assertTrue(problems.toString(), problems.isEmpty());
```

Comment: I didn't want to fail within a loop, I want the testcase to print **all** issues to me, instead of failing on the first one.

Comment: @GhostCat oh  so you want to report all the problems at once?

Comment: @Michael that error message is going to look very funny for 3 of the same values...

Comment: @Eugene I considered that and did a test for it locally. Sample output: *key 1 mapped to OTHER and SOME_CONST, key 1 mapped to TEST and OTHER*. I don't think that's particularly bad, personally. Maybe not the optimal error message, but he asked how he could make the code of the test more readable, and to some extent there must be a trade-off.

Comment: @Michael it looks ugly, IMO. You can take ernest answer that does the computing of the map, stream that, filter where the size > 1, and print all messages, at once; thus no trade offs

Comment: @Eugene The trade-off becomes the complexity of the assertion. My assertion is a single obvious line. GhostCat's assertion, and any assertion based on iterating the map's keys, is necessarily more complex.

Comment: @Michael right. I guess its the OP to decide, *I* would go for something else

Comment: @Eugene And me. I'd use the `assertNull` version. Running a test multiple times to eliminate all of the failures is fairly common. It's only in very specific cases like these where you can *know* that all possible failures can be detected in a single run of the test.